# Graphical method of solving quadratic and cubic equations

Tags: polynomials, quadratics

I once came across a method for solving quadratic and cubic equations using a graphical method as shown below (where the lengths of the line segments are equal to the coefficients of the equation). However, I can't remember what to do after I have drawn these line segments.

[image: visual representation of x^2 + 5x + 6 = 0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is [Lill's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lill%27s_method) for general (real) polynomial roots. After drawing the line segments you cast a ray from the isolated endpoint of the line segment corresponding to the highest-power term, turning $90^\circ$ at (the extension of) each segment corresponding to the polynomial's remaining terms, according to the following rules:

- if the ray hits the segment itself, it stays on the same side (is reflected)
- if not, it goes to the opposite side (is refracted)

[image]

If this ray eventually hits the other endpoint after all the turns, the slope of the initial ray (before its first turn) corresponds to a root of the polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

Your graph [image]*wants* to represent the equation

$$x^2+5x+6=0$$

but it begins from the first point to the **left** instead of to the right. No problem, I will adjust my explanation to it - as you correctly turn **clockwise** (and not counter-clockwise) for plus signs in coefficients $+5$ and $+6$.)

First which is need to say is, that searching for roots **is not a direct geometric construction** (in the sense e. g. of an edge and compass) but something as **groping around** or **guessing**, but with a quick feedback about a success.

(Something as dividing the segment into $3$ equal parts only by guessing - a quick feedback about a success gives you your eyes.)

Second, **it is not a method to find exact values of roots**, as the final judge is you, your eyes.

In a summary, the **Lill's method** (which is its name by its inventor [Eduard Lill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduard_Lill)), *is nothing more that a method for a good guessing (and iteratively correcting the guesses) because the quick feedback is very illustrative.*

**Now, what we are guessing?**

*The slope of the ray from point A* - because it *will be a root*.

So, lets start with a bad guess. Your equation has roots $-2$ and $-3$, but we will guess $\color{red}{-1}$. Here is the ray $\color{red}k$ with slope $\color{red}{-1}$:
[image]
It intersect the line $i=BC$ in the point $E$.

Now we construct the perpendicular line $l$ to this ray in point $E$:

[image]

It intersects the line $j=CD$ in the point $F$ - and **it is different from the point $D$**.
So the quick feedback doesn't approve the value $\color{red}{-1}$.

But in spite of it this feedback gives us an **idea** - we need to move the point $E$ a little upwards for reaching a goal - the coincidence of point $\color{red}F$ with point $\color{blue}D$).

Now we use value (slope) $\color{red}{-2}$, which IS a root of your equation:

[image]

Do you see the coincidence of $\color{red}F$ with $\color{blue}D$?
The quick feedback now approves the value $\color{red}{-2}$ as a root of your equation.

Similarly for value (slope) $\color{red}{-3}$:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As an illustration for searching for roots of the equation

$$x^2+5x+6=0$$

(which are $-2$ and $-3$) by Lill's method, here is  an animation of it:

[image]